# Which is the best way to connect two API with RabbitMQ and Docker?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I need to create two APIs with .Net Core 3.1.
Lets call them "API 1" and "API 2".

API 1 will receive a HTTP Post with some information, and send it with RabbitMQ to API 2.
API 2 will process this information and send the result to API 1 again with RabbitMQ.

The requisite is to use Docker.. so, which is the best way to implement this infrastructure?

- Create two solutions with one project each one? How I can connect them? Because each one will have their own docker container.
- Create one solution with two projects? I try this one, but I don't know how start the second project (API 2).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It will explain why asking "which is best" questions falls under the category of opinion based questions and why those aren't a good match for this site.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to run multiple apps inside one container, but [not recommended](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

The optimal solution is probably (at least) three containers:

1. Service (API) 1
2. Service (API) 2
3. RabbitMQ (unless you have a running instance of this already)

Using multiple containers has a number of benefits, including easier setup, debugging and scaling. If for instance you'd find out your second service is the bottleneck, you could start an additional instance of that service to speed things up without creating more (unneeded) instances of the first service or RabbitMQ.

You then need to [configure a network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) for these containers that allow communication among them. I'd also suggest having a look at [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for your development environment since that handles setting up the network between services for you.